# Context Menu when right click exe

Tags: c#, contextmenu

When Outlook is pinned to your taskbar and it is not running, if you right click on it you will see option to create a new email, new appointment, etc. I'd like to add options like this to my C# console application. So that when certain options are selected it will do different things. I thought it was called context menu but I am not sure. All I can find is how to add context menus to the form and not the exe itself. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I believe the menu is called a "jump list".

Comment: These are Shortcut Menu Handlers for the Windows Shell. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers

Comment: [JumpList Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.jumplist).